# Open new tab on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I want to open new tab on button click, button that clicked is exist on a Iframe.

I use this code--

```
string tempabc = "javascript:window.open('ReportViewer.aspx?ReportType=" + rptnew + "&Billno=" + billno + "&Mail=" + "Mail" + "&CCMail=" + CCMail + "&Subject=" + txtSubject.Text + "&MailBody=" + txtMailBody.Text + "')";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", tempabc, true);
```

but it should't show any result.

then I can use this code-

```
Response.Redirect("ReportViewer.aspx?ReportType=" + rptnew + "&Billno=" + billno + "&Mail=" + "Mail" + "&CCMail=" + CCMail + "&Subject=" + txtSubject.Text + "&MailBody=" + txtMailBody.Text + "'");
```

It will open the next page on same Iframe.

what I can do.

In my .aspx page I can use that tags.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelMail" runat="server">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel15" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                      <table>                    
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                <center>
                                    <asp:Button ID="BtnMail" Style="" Text="Mail" CssClass="btnn" runat="server" OnClick="BtnMail_Click"
                                        OnClientClick="return MailSubmit();" />
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnMail" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
string tempabc = "javascript:window.open('ReportViewer.aspx?ReportType=" + rptnew + "&Billno=" + billno + "&Mail=" + "Mail" + "&CCMail=" + CCMail + "&Subject=" + txtSubject.Text + "&MailBody=" + txtMailBody.Text + "','_blank')";
```

Or

Add  `formtarget="_blank"` attribute in your button

Or

```
<button  onclick="a()">Click Me</button> 
<script>
function a()
{
    window.open('url', '_blank', 'width=300,height=200');
}
</script>
```

If you didn't mention the `size` it will open in `new tab` otherwise as a `popup`.

```
window.open('url', '_blank') - next tab
window.open('url', '_blank','width=300,height=200') - popup
```

Comment: same thing happen in this code also, not show any response.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Have you checked formtarget="_blank" attribute in your button . this is an html 5 tag. hope this will help you

Comment: hi @Abhishek  please checkout my edited answer (last one ) hope that will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your current `tempabc` string with this one :

```
string tempabc = "javascript:window.open('ReportViewer.aspx?ReportType=" + rptnew + "&Billno=" + billno + "&Mail=" + "Mail" + "&CCMail=" + CCMail + "&Subject=" + txtSubject.Text + "&MailBody=" + txtMailBody.Text + "','_newtab')";
```

Added the `'_newtab'` attribute to open it in a new tab.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this also

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
    onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';" />
```

EDIT

Then try this :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 function SetTarget() {
     document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
 }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
    onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick = "SetTarget();" />
```

Here you can put multiple functions.

Comment: Sir, onClientClick I can check some validations then where I can use this code, but I 'll try it..

Comment: Ya sir, I'll check it and also apply on my code but It can't show any response.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you show me what you doing on your `.aspx` page ?

Comment: In your Question..Edit your question  @Abhishek

Comment: Sir I am not able to show, I can try more to edit my question but after adding my .aspx page code it will show error for Identing my code I can also indent it but not allow me for posting the changes.

Comment: sir I you don't mind then I can mail you the code on your mail Id, If you provide me your mail ID.